# How can I get a list of providers used in a resource group?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Given an Azure subscription ID and resource group name, how can I get a list of all provider(s) that make up the resources in that group? E.g. if a RG contains websites and VMs, I'd get `["Microsoft.Website", "Microsoft.Compute"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to do this is by using the [List By Resource Group API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup), then parsing the resource IDs manually.